# Fast throw unhandled exceptions in TPL

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

My problem: I want to use TPL in WinForms application under .NET 4 and **I need the task continuations to elevate any unhandled exceptions immediately ("fast throw") instead of waiting for `GC` collecting the `Task`.** Is it possible?

In .NET 4.5 with `async/await` support it is possible to write:

```
Public Class AwaitForm
    Inherits Form

    Private Async Sub Execute()
        Dim uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()

        Try
            Await Me.LongWork().
                ContinueWith(Sub(t) Me.LongWorkCompleted(), uiScheduler)

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' yay, possible to handle here
            ' eg. MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Async Function LongWork() As Task
        Await Task.Delay(1000)
    End Function

    Private Sub LongWorkCompleted()
        Throw New Exception("Ups")
    End Sub

End Class
```

The exception in continuation would be thrown immediately if not handled in `Excecute` method.

How to achieve same behavior in .NET 4 without `async/await` support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should know it's possible to use async-await with .Net 4.0 with [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

But without it, you can add a continuation to the task with `ContinueWith` and have it run only when there was an exception with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`

```
Me.LongWork().ContinueWith(Sub(task) MsgBox(task.Exception.Message), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
```

Comment: That does not answer my question - I wanted to "fast-throw" any unhandled exceptions. Maybe I introduced some confusion because of the example with handler. But imagine there was no handler. Or it is always possible that any exception handler will raise exception itself. I want those exceptions to be thrown immediately without TPL swallowing them as UnobservedTaskException.

Comment: To elevate and bubble the exception through the whole call stack. There might be my custom handlers on the way which will handle it properly. Without handlers tearing down app, yes.

Comment: @mancze There's no call stack on a task to bubble up on as long as there's no thread waiting for it. You can just block on the task with `Task.Wait` but then using TPL to begin with would be pointless.

Comment: I see, you've got point about the task having no specific call stack on it's own. Unless I schedule task to the specific thread (ui thread).
Calling `Wait` does the trick but blocks the ui thread which I do not want to. I want to "`Wait`" as soon, as exception is thrown. Having continuation with `Wait` is no-go, because again - it's unhandled exceptions would be trapped by TPL.

Comment: I will gladly mark your answer as solution because you correctly pointed that `async/await` support can be added via `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. It helped me to find my own solution. I would be happy if you could emphasize this part of your answer. The later part is not-so-relevant.

Comment: @mancze If you want to marshal the exception back to the UI thread, it's as simple as using a synchronization context for your exceptional continuation (`OnlyOnFaulted`). However, to be able to use try-catch (and `using` etc.) over an asynchronous task, you have to use `await` - that's part of the "magic" it does. You can do the same thing manually, but it will definitely not look synchronous - and it's easy to get wrong.

Comment: @Luaan actually yes - marshaling back to selected (ui) thread corresponds to what I need. I was looking for some neat hi-level way to do it without the need to touch threads, contexts and so. I thought there could be something builtin. As you can see in my solution I ended up with exactly what you suggest but wrapped into simpler-to-use code. And about the ability to use try-catch: generally you are right, however I can run message queue (`Application.Run` or also `ShowDialog`) inside try-catch block which would allow me to catch those kind of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is either possible to use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` as i3arnon suggested.

2) Or if you do not want to reference extra libraries I have came up with the solution based on the `async/await`. The magic behind is yucky but it's best I've got.

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Threading


Public Module TaskExtensions

    ''' <summary>Throws the exception on the current SynchronizationContext or ThreadPool if there is none.</summary>
    ''' <param name="task">Task whose faulted continuation should throw exception.</param>
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub ThrowOnFaulted(task As Task)
        Dim context = SynchronizationContext.Current
        ThrowOnFaulted(task, context)
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>Throws the exception on the ThreadPool in given context.</summary>
    ''' <param name="task">Task whose faulted continuation should throw exception.</param>
    ''' <param name="targetContext">The target context on which to propagate the exception. Null to use the ThreadPool.</param>
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub ThrowOnFaulted(task As Task, targetContext As SynchronizationContext)
        task.ContinueWith(Sub(t) ThrowOnFaultedCore(t, targetContext), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
    End Sub


    ''' <remarks>Taken from System.RunTime.CompilerServices.AsyncServices.</remarks>
    Private Sub ThrowOnFaultedCore(task As Task, targetContext As SynchronizationContext)
        Dim exception = task.Exception

        If targetContext IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                targetContext.Post(Sub(state) Throw DirectCast(state, Exception), exception)
                Return
            Catch ex As Exception
                exception = New AggregateException({exception, ex})
            End Try
        End If

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub(state) Throw DirectCast(state, Exception), exception)
    End Sub

End Module
```

It meets the requirements - exception is thrown "fast" and is can be handled. The exception is `Post`ed to the target `SynchronizationContext` thus escaping the TPL's exception trapping mechanism. It's far from fast and synchronous but at least it behaves better than waiting for task disposal.